# Is there any way to reload an asp.net core application using dotnet-cli?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using visual code and I am looking to reload the web application once I make any changes within my MVC code files. I know we can Ctrl+C to shutdown the app and and then reload by typing `dotnet run`.

Is there any faster like we had nodemon in NodeJS web application development?

Comment: [`dotnet watch run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch)?

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dotnet build` to build your application and then `dotnet watch run` to run it.
You might need `dotnet restore`to restore all the NuGet packages.

For more details check this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x